# Proving limit relations with the exponential function

Tags: real-analysis, exponential-function

> Prove the following limit relations:
>
> $$\lim_{x\to0} (1+x)^{1/x} = e$$
>
> $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1 + \frac{x}{n}\right)^n = e^x$$

I'm not sure how to prove this as I'm not really sure what tools I have to prove it. I know by definition that the two limit relations are true, but any advice as to how to solve this specific problem/similar problems would be very appreciated!

Comment: Define $e$ and define $e^x$.  These limits are often given as the definitions.

Comment: @Dr.MV I don't think my professor wants us to just give the definitions, though - he wants a technical proof of some sort.

Comment: The question is "How does one define $e$?"  Without a starting definition, one cannot proceed.

Comment: In your 2nd limit, do you mean n goes to infinity?

Comment: @Omry I do, thank you!

Comment: @mizichael You wrote `I know by definition that the two limit relations are true` but also ask `how to prove this`. You don't/can't prove definitions, so what's being asked here is what are the *actual* definitions you work with, and what remains to be proved using those definitions.

Comment: @Dr.MV I suppose that's part of the problem - I'm not sure how we're meant to define it. I was hoping someone on here might have a little insight as to what we might be able to assume about $e$.

Comment: [See This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characterizations_of_the_exponential_function#Characterizations).  Pick one.

Comment: @Dr.MV This is part of my problem - the first definition on the page is exactly what I'm supposed to be ending up with. I don't think my professor wants me to just copy it down. As I'm working a little ahead we haven't done much work with the actual definitions of $e$, so I was wondering if one of those 6 definitions came "first", in a way. Or, one of the definitions was the "original" definition of $e$, and the others are simply consequences of the first.

Comment: I don't know which characterization your professor has chosen implicitly.  Have you covered Taylor series?

Answer (score 0):

If we let x=1 in the second limit is very easy to prove they are the same limit, you make a change of variable n=1/x, as x approaches 0, n tends to infinity, so you just replace in the limit and they both tend to e